# How to search in a json field that contains an array of objects with Eloquent

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm trying to seach in JSON field with Eloquent, but now work, seach with 0 results.

This is for Ubuntu server, running PostgresSQL, Laravel 5.8 and Apache 2.

```
[{
    "value": "1",
    "label": "numero"
},{
    "value": "2016",
    "label": "anio"
},{
    "value": "Acer",
    "label": "especie"
},{
    "value": "2",
    "label": "cant_plantar"
}]
```

```
PlanificacionInfo::select('datos_complementarios')->WhereJsonContains('datos_complementarios', ["value" => "Escamonda 2019"]);
```

The query returns empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL requires the object value to be inside an array:

```php
PlanificacionInfo::select('datos_complementarios')
    ->whereJsonContains('datos_complementarios', [["value" => "Escamonda 2019"]]);
```

Use a raw expression for case-insensitive search:

```php
PlanificacionInfo::select('datos_complementarios')
    ->whereJsonContains(
        DB::raw('lower("datos_complementarios"::text)'),
        [["value" => strtolower("Escamonda 2019")]]
    );
```

Comment: It's work, but I'm need to make it ignore case, how could I do it?

Comment: I have another question for you, how to use this to search without putting the full value, for example "Escamonda 201"? Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure PostgreSQL doesn't support that.

Comment: How would you run this in mysql? It gives the error Unknown column 'lower("datos_complementarios"::text)'

Comment: @GotaloveCode What's the whole error message?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it with a lower-case 'w' in `->whereJsonContains`? Like so:

```
PlanificacionInfo::select('datos_complementarios')
    ->whereJsonContains('datos_complementarios', ["value" => "Escamonda 2019"]);
```

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries), you may have to do something like this:

```
$users = PlanificacionInfo::select('datos_complementarios')
        ->whereJsonContains('datos_complementarios->value', 'YOUR SEARCH TERM HERE')
        ->get();
```

Also, there doesn't appear to be any matching json for your query in the sample you have given in your question - does "Escamonda 2019" appear in your data?

Comment: Same result.
Yes, "Escamonda 2019" exist in the data, the JSON is extracted from the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your json into a PHP associative array first:

```
//your json
$raw = '[{
    "value": "1",
    "label": "numero"
},{
    "value": "2016",
    "label": "anio"
},{
    "value": "Acer",
    "label": "especie"
},{
    "value": "2",
    "label": "cant_plantar"
}]';

//convert json to associative array
$decoded = json_decode($raw, true);
```

here's a function to filter and find matches "value"=>$searchWord

```
//reusable function

function searchValue($array, $searchWord)
{
  $result = array_filter($array,
    function ($item) use ($searchWord) {
      return $item['value'] == $searchWord;
    }
  );
  return $result;
}
```

simply call your function:

```
//the call
$query = searchValue($decoded, "Acer");
var_dump($query);
```